# Update table result

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables. In the UniqueZips table there is a code field assigned,
my goal is to match the fields of each window from both tables and assign the code from the Uniquezips table to the Route tbl but the code below doesn't work any suggestions?

```
UPDATE [Route tbl], UniqueZips
SET [Route tbl].CODE = [UniqueZips]![CODE]
WHERE (([Route tbl]![WINDOW 1]=[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 1] &
     [Route tbl]![WINDOW 2]=[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 2] &
     [Route tbl]![WINDOW 3]=[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 3] & 
     [Route tbl]![WINDOW 4]=[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 4] & 
     [Route tbl]![WINDOW 5]=[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 5]));
```

I've also tired this

```
  UPDATE UniqueZips  
  INNER JOIN [Route tbl] ON (UniqueZips.[WINDOW 3] = [Route tbl].[WINDOW 3])
  AND (UniqueZips.[WINDOW 5] = [Route tbl].[WINDOW 5]) 
  AND (UniqueZips.[WINDOW 4] = [Route tbl].[WINDOW 4]) 
  AND (UniqueZips.[WINDOW 2] = [Route tbl].[WINDOW 2])
  AND (UniqueZips.[WINDOW 1] = [Route tbl].[WINDOW 1]) 
  SET [Route tbl].CODE = [UniqueZips]![CODE]
  WHERE ((([Route tbl]![WINDOW 1]=[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 1]
        & [Route tbl]![WINDOW 2]= [UniqueZips]![WINDOW 2] 
        & [Route tbl]![WINDOW 3]=[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 3]
        & [Route tbl]![WINDOW 4]=[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 4] 
        & [Route tbl]![WINDOW 5])=[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 5]));
```

okay so before i was getting no results but now ive tried this

```
      UPDATE [Route tbl], UniqueZips 
      SET [Route tbl].CODE = [UniqueZips]![CODE]
      WHERE (((StrComp([Route tbl]![WINDOW 1],[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 1]) & 
            StrComp([Route tbl]![WINDOW 2],[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 2]) & 
            StrComp([Route tbl]![WINDOW 3],[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 3]) & 
            StrComp([Route tbl]![WINDOW 4],[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 4]) &
            StrComp([Route tbl]![WINDOW 5],[UniqueZips]![WINDOW 5]))="0"));
```

this however matches them but incorrectly, any help with all this mess ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'window'? Have you got two forms open, and if so, what type of forms? If it is forms, this could be much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pleas don't kick yourself too hard...

I think the first two will work perfectly once you replace the string concatenation operator `&` with the keyword `AND`.